# Software Update command (on Mac) not listing all the updates

Tags: macos, terminal, software-update

On regular basis, I check for OS and App updates using terminal and `softwareupdate` command

Recently, there was update of `Slack` app but command output didn't show the same. I was able to view update on AppStore.

Below was the output of the command.

```
$ softwareupdate -all
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-10.0
    Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode (10.0), 190520K [recommended]
   * Safari12.0HighSierraAuto-12.0
    Safari (12.0), 78915K [recommended]
```

Any reason why `Slack` update was not listed? Am I missing any parameter?

Comment: what is a Slack ?

Comment: it only lists apple sw

Answer (score 2):

`softwareupdate` only handles updates to the OS and bundled software, not purchased (/free) apps. The distinction isn't always obvious; the clearest way I have to describe it is that if an app is tied to (/owned by) a particular Apple ID, then `softwareupdate` won't handle it. Safari and iTunes are examples of apps that just come with the OS, therefore aren't owned by any specific Apple ID, and therefore *are* handled by `softwareupdate`. On the other hand, Slack is an app you "purchase" (it's free, but it's still technically a purchase) under your Apple ID in the App Store, therefore `softwareupdate` does not handle it.

Andrew Naylor has written a CLI interface to deal with App Store purchases (including updates), available from https://github.com/mas-cli/mas.

Update: in macOS Mojave, the distinction is clear in the GUI as well as at the command line. In Mojave, the App Store interface *only* handles updates to "purchased" apps, while OS and bundled software updates are handled by the Software Update pane in System Preferences. So "Software Update" preferences == `softwareupdate` command, and "App Store" application == Andrew Naylor's `mas` command.